# unable to share video in facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, video

I want to share video in Facebook.
For that I have download and set up FacebookSDK as per their documentation.
For that If I go with their tutorial code that works fine as per below.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
    video.videoURL = videoURL;
    NSLog("%@",videoURL);
    FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
    content.video = video;
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
}
```

logging comes as per below

> asset
>   URL:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=7D4D3554-6782-446F-A566-BD570754B6ED&ext=JPG

But if I change code as per my requirement then video is not going to appear in share dialog. The code is as per below.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Saved Video"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[player.contentURL lastPathComponent]];;
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];//[NSURL URLWithString:myPathDocs];
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;
NSLog("%@",myPathDocs);
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
```

logging comes as per below

> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4DF2C574-4A9D-41B8-8666-27472A995F47/Documents/Saved%20Video/hello.mov

My video size not greater then 12MB as per mention in facebook documentation for video sharing.

I have also tried like following
`video.videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];`

For that logging is as below.

> file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4DF2C574-4A9D-41B8-8666-27472A995F47/Documents/Saved%2520Video/hello.mov

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: here , player means object of `MPMoviePlayerController` which is currently playing video .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
    content.video = [FBSDKShareVideo videoWithVideoURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs]];
```